# I am unable to get values in twig template in drupal 9

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-9

I have mapped the fields of a content type (a webform) to node using **Webform content creator** in **drupal 9** now the issue is that i am not getting those mapped fields in my twig template. All I am getting are previously mapped values. I have double checked the fields in content type and mapping in webform content creator.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes, I have cleared all the caches twice. But still unable to see data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Drupal module **Devel** (https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to find the right key to display.

Or **debug in twig** some of these:

- {{ content.field_name.0 }}
- {{ node.field_name.0.target_id }}

**get keys you need:**

```
{{ dump(content|keys) }}
```

**dump like this for small fields:**

```
{% for k,v in content.field_name  %}
  - {{ k }}: {{ dump(v.value) }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

*the variable **content.field_name** can be changed if you found the right field from your dump before*